# What is the equivalent directive in Apache 2.4?

Tags: apache-2.4

I am upgrading from an earlier version of Apache (2.2) to Apache 2.4. I noticed a couple of directives did not work. While I implemented a solution and it seems to work, I wanted to check to see if anyone knew if these were the correct ones.

```
Pre 2.4 configuration

<Location /blahblah>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from *.blahblah.com
</Location>

2.4 configuration

<Location /blahblah>
    Require all denied
    Require host blahblah.com
</Location>



Pre 2.4 configuration

<Location /blahblah1>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>

2.4 configuration

<Location /blahblah1>
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question.

Comment: The wildcard in pre 2.4 (Allow from *.domain.com) and lack thereof in 2.4 seemed odd. I wanted to confirm that I was doing this right.